# Use SBT to manage XML resources (required at runtime) from an external git repository

Tags: git, scala, resources, sbt

I have a Scala project in SBT, and at runtime it needs to access a collection of XML files which I would like fetch from git and put on the classpath at build time. These XMLs come from an external git repository that I have no control over, so I can't merge the two repos.

I see that SBT allows you to add `unmanagedResourceDirectories` and `managedResoureDirectories` (not sure what the difference is), which allows you to instruct SBT to add directories to the classpath, but I'm not sure how to get the directory from a git repo, rather than an actual directory on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [JGit library](https://eclipse.org/jgit/) to clone the repo locally and copy the files out of the repo using the `archive` command. As an example, see how the [sbt-hackling](https://github.com/libling/sbt-hackling) plugin implements this.

If you don't need platform-independence, you can get by with invoking the command line git commands and combine `clone`/`fetch` to update the dependency and `archive` to extract files.

The part of the code that copies some paths out of a local repository:

```
// needed for installSource
// maybe implement some archiver to go directly to files?
org.eclipse.jgit.archive.ArchiveFormats.registerAll()

def installSource(cachedRepo: Git, paths: Seq[String], revision: ObjectId, target: File): Set[File] =
    IO.withTemporaryFile(target.getName, ".zip") { tmp =>
    val out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tmp))

    cachedRepo
        .archive()
        .setFormat("zip")
        .setTree(revision)
        .setPaths(paths :_*)
        .setOutputStream(out)
        .call()

    IO.unzip(tmp, target)
    }
```

Part of code that clones a repo locally:

```
def downloadGitRepo(local: File)(repo: URI): File = {

    val clone = Git
        .cloneRepository()
        .setURI(repo.toString)
        .setDirectory(local)
        .setBare(true)
        .call()

    assert(local.exists())

    local
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer! I'll try this out later today and mark accepted if it works :-)